Safest way to incrementally append to a file?
I'm performing some calculations to generate chaotic solutions to a mathematical function. I have an infinite loop that looks something like this:
f = open('solutions.csv', 'a')
while True:
    x = generate_random_parameters() # x is a list of floats
    success = test_parameters(x)
    if success:
        print(','.join(map(str, x)), file=f, flush=True)

The implementation of generate_random_parameters() and test_parameters() is not very important here.
When I want to stop generating solutions I want to ^C, but I want to ensure that solutions.csv keeps its integrity/doesn't get corrupted/etc, in case I happen to interrupt when the file is being written to.
So far I haven't observed this happening, but I'd like to remove any possibility that this could occur.
Additionally, since the program will never terminate on its own I don't have a corresponding f.close() -- this should be fine, correct?
Appreciate any clarification.

Use with open(…) as f:

I'm used to using with open(...) as f, but for this situation I didn't know if it was better to do so. My basic understanding of the with block is that it's a safe way to ensure the file is closed after exiting from the block, but if I'm ^C-ing anyway, is there still an advantage?

One simple approach to ensuring that the current call to print finishes before the program exits from a keyboard interrupt is to use a signal handler to unset a flag on which the while loop runs.
Set the signal handler only when you're about to call print and reset the signal handler to the original when print returns, so that the preceding code in the loop can be interrupted normally:
import signal

def interrupt_handler(signum, frame):
    global running
    running = False

text = 'a' * 99999
running = True
with open('solutions.csv', 'a') as f:
    while running:
        ... # your calculations
        original_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupt_handler)
        print(text, file=f, flush=True) # your output
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_handler)

Also note that it is more idiomatic to use open as a context manager to handle the closure of an open file when exiting the block for any reason.

Thanks, I like this approach. But this would make each iteration of the loop run till completion - not just the filewriting. If the calculations step is costly/time consuming, I'd like to interrupt immediately. It's only the filewriting instruction that I don't want to interrupt.

I see. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Great, thanks again. This looks like exactly what I need. I was also trying to figure out how to 'restore' the original signal handler, didn't realize this is how the syntax worked. +1

It's generally good practice to use the with context manager anytime you're opening a file, it will auto handle file closure and be generally safer to ctrl-c out of.(pylint,pep)
with open('solutions.csv', 'a') as f:
    while True:
        x = generate_random_parameters()
        success = test_parameters(x)
        if success:
            print(','.join(map(str, x)), file=f, flush=True)

Your code, is technically fine without using the context manager but in the event of an exception having file.close() execute is never a bad thing.

The OP's current code is not technically fine because print makes at least two system calls, one to write the given string, and another to write a newline, and a keyboard interrupt can occur between the two system calls, resulting in a corrupt file without a trailing newline.

@blhsing It seems bizarre to me that one might have to account for a built-in Python function's underlying implementation.
